# Pre-Processing Raw Texts Before Running Vader or TextBlob Sentiment Analysis?

Tags: python-3.x, sentiment-analysis

I learned from a few examples that one needs to pre-process raw texts (e.g. removing stop-words, punctuation, applying lower-case, lemmatizing, and etc) before running a sentiment analysis.

However, when I saw some example codes for sentiment analysis using Vader or TextBlob, those example codes do not go over pre-process steps but rather the codes are directly applied to raw texts.

Based on my impression, it seems that people pre-process raw texts when they want to train and test the model by themselves (in this case, corresponding labels such as positive or negative are identified) whereas they do not go over pre-process steps when they choose to run unsupervised sentiment analysis (e.g. TextBlob, vader).

Or is there any other reasons for whether we decide to pre-process or not?
Any helpful comments will be appreciated.